# why -5 is smaller than -7

Tags: python, list, min

'''

```
x = list(input('Please enter a list of different numbers separated by \',\':').split(','))
min = x[0]
for i in range(0,len(x)):
    if x[i] < min:
        min = x [i]
print('The minimun number is ',min)
```

'''

if I input 5,-5,-7 the output is -5 instead of -7
may I know there is the problem

Comment: You aren't checking if `-5 < -7`, you are testing if `"-5" < "-7"`. Strings compare lexicographically.

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing strings, not integers.

Also, you are overriding the built-in `min` function which accepts a list

```
>>> min(int(x) for x in input('Please enter a list of different numbers separated by \',\':').split(','))
Please enter a list of different numbers separated by ',':-5,5,-7
-7
```

Comment: I think it's better to use `float` instead of `int`, so you can compare all numbers, not only integers.

Comment: @Cardstdani That conflicts with the author's intent. Floats were never mentioned

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the values to a number type like `float` to compare them:

```
x = input('Please enter a list of different numbers separated by \',\':')
x = x.split(",")
x = list(map(float, x))
print('The minimun number is ', min(x))
```